# Authorization Method on Adwords

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I've just got back to working on an integration with the Adwords API, and realized it had to be upgraded (from v201109).

This was previously a prototype application, that is now scheduled to come to life, and what I've noticed is that there's been a big leap from v201109 to v201209 in terms of authentication.

By reading Takeshi's reply [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adwords-api/Q4RlHPGNLzU/ZWoc38H05gsJ), it became clear that the entire concept of sandbox has now been phased out, and we now work on the basis of having a test account.

Initially on my prototype I was only using ClientLogin as the AuthorizationMethod through a test account. However, with the new authentication I've realized I will actually have to use our actual live MCC account with a test account as described [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts).

All well and good, I've got the account created, and have requested permission to use it as a test account. However using the live credentials with

```
<add key="AuthorizationMethod" value="ClientLogin" />
<add key="Email" value="xxx"/>
<add key="Password" value="xxxxx"/>
```

Isn't an option... :-(

I then thought about requesting an OAuth key pair in order to use them on my application instead. All the documentation I found about getting one of those seems a bit rough around the edges, so I'm not really sure how to get one of those without actually making my application request it. Ideally, I'd like to go somewhere, generate it, and then use it on my config file as such.

```
<add key="AuthorizationMethod" value="OAuth" />
<add key="OAuthConsumerKey" value="INSERT_YOUR_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY_HERE" />
<add key="OAuthConsumerSecret" value="INSERT_YOUR_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE" />
```

Is that even possible? If so, where can I generate the OAuth keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you still can use ClientLogin, but it's been earmarked for deprecation, which means Google will still support it for the next 3 or so years.

Here's a link to a conversation between Anash (AdWords API Advisor) and myself on the Google Adwords API official forum.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/adwords-api/C-giDgpvF_I/discussion